# How can I retrieve the biggest date and time from the column using Linq to entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have datetime column named `DateMeasure` in sql table.

I use entity framework 6 in my .net project.

Here is example of my table:

```
 Id           | NumberP  | TrackNumber | DateMeasure
28092|15240000|1.0.7.1782|2009040004731|2008-01-20 13:10:22.000
28094|61615000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007696|2010-05-20 13:11:38.000
28095|95317000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007695|2011-08-20 13:10:18.000
28101|15240000|1.0.7.1782|2009040004740|2015-11-20 14:10:22.000
28103|61615000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007690|2015-11-20 14:11:38.000
28104|95317000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007710|2009-02-20 14:10:18.000
```

The row that I want to get from table with help of Linq to entity:

```
28103|61615000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007690|2015-11-20 14:11:38.000
```

How can I retrieve the biggest(latest) **date and time** from the column using Linq to entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max date using `Max` extension:

```
var maxDate = context.Table.Max(m => m.DateMeasure);
```

Then, you can use `FirstOrDefault` to get that entity:

```
var model = context.Table.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DateMeasure == maxDate);
```

Actually, you can do it in just one query:

```
var model = context.Table.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DateMeasure == context.Table.Max(x => x.DateMeasure));
```

Comment: Arturo, is it take into the account hour minutes and seconds?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, all date and time parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OrderBy` methods of a IQuery object in Linq to sort by the `DateMeasure` column and fetch the first entry.

```
(from s in context.Table
       orderby s.DateMeasure descending).First()
```

Or with:

```
context.Table
       .OrderByDescending(s => s.DateMeasure)
       .First();
```

The `OrderByDescending` method will sort the query in descending order, you can also use `OrderBy` to sort by ascending order.